# How to benchmark Web/REST MVC frameworks?

Tags: performance, rest, model-view-controller, web, benchmarking

I am trying to find the fastest and reliable MVC framework/stack for our new project. I have tried and failed after googling it.

The requirements for my projects are

- No preferences in language or stack. It can be php, python, java or ruby.
- RESTful API support.
- Faster response time.
- Ability to process database transactions faster.

**Question**

What are the key factors to consider while benchmarking MVC Frameworks? Suggest some language agnostic and platform/stack independent benchmarking tools.

Comment: Have you tried [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I have not used it yet. Will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Theres an incredibly (almost overly) in depth benchmarking of tech stacks and frameworks that can be found here:  https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/

It should list metrics for your metrics requirements (response and transaction time).